# $pq+1$ is a square $\iff$ $p$ and $q$ are twin primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

This exercise if from Beachy and Blairs Abtract algebra book.

Assume that $p$ and $q$ are primes.

Show that: $pq+1$ is square $\iff$ $p$ and $q$ are twin primes.

The backward direction is:
Assume that 
$$p=q+2$$
then 
$$pq+1=q^2+2q+1=(q+1)^2.$$

For the forward direction: we assume that
$$pq+1$$
is a square that is
$$pq+1=n^2\Rightarrow pq=(n-1)(n+1).$$
Now since $p$ and $q$ are primes by assumption and prime factorisation is unique we have 
$$p=n-1\qquad q=n+1$$ 
so $p$ and $q$ are two apart therefore are twins.

First of all in my original question I forgot a really important assumtion that both of $p$ and $q$ are primes from the beginning. I am sorry for this mistake. So some of the comments may be irrelevant now when I edited the question (I hope it is correct now). Thanks for the comments and again sorry for the incorrect citation of the question.

Comment: Are you sure that $p$ and $q$ being primes is not a hypothesis for the whole of the "if and only if"?

Comment: This is an old question with several solutions on the web, e.g., see [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080626165502AATdpqp), or [here](http://mathhelpforum.com/number-theory/105603-primes-squares.html).

Comment: $p=2$, $q=4$ satisfies $pq+1=n^2$ but $p$ and $q$ are not twin primes.

Comment: Well, for example $15^2 = 225 = 14 \times 16 +1$ but $14$ and $16$ are not primes ...

Comment: @PabloRotondo you were totally correct! thank you for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are missing somethin, in fact your proof is wrong on at least two points.

---

First of all, you need to assume that $p$ and $q$ are primes for the forward direction to even work, since otherwise, you could have $p=6$ and $q=4$ to get $pq+1=25=5^2$.

Second of all, you go from

$$pq=(n+1)(n-1)$$ straight to "therefore, $p$ and $q$ are two appart, which is faulty logic since you assume $$ab=cd \implies \{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$$ which is false in general. For example, $3\cdot 8 = (5+1)(5-1)$, however that does not mean that $\{3,8\}=\{4,6\}$. Of course, if you know that $a$ and $b$ are primes, then it is possible to show this, but still, you can't just assume it is true.

---

**After the edit**:

Your proof is now correct. Using the unique factorisation is a quick and easy way to prove the statement, and it's also clear why you need to assume $p,q$ are primes (and how $4,6$ fails in that step).

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa If you correct your proof by editing the question, I will be happy to review it. Just leave a message in the comments to my answer so I get a notification.

Comment: I think the fact that the OP shows with its "proof" that he does not need the fact that $p,q$ are twin primes to show that $pq+1$ can be a square demonstrate at minimum that the assumption (the equivalence) is flat wrong, as you yourself demonstrated. in fact $ n \in \mathbb{N}, n(n+2)+1$ is a square, trivially...

Comment: ok. I get to it straight away. thank you again

Comment: i edited now, I think it is correct.

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa Your proof is now correct. Using the unique factorisation is a quick and easy way to prove the statement, and it's also clear why you need to assume $p,q$ are primes

Comment: exactly, again sorry for the wrong question. but now my question is not a question anymore, so how to remove it? this is something I usually wonder about

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa Since people can still learn from your question, you shouldn't remove it. Instead, I suggest you accept my answer...

Comment: ok, actually i do not think I can remove it.